# Is there a way to force re-election in Apache mesos master quorum?

Tags: mesos

We have a Apache Mesos master running in HA mode with 3 nodes(each with 4CPU, 15G Memory), this cluster stops offering resources when the memory gets completely exhausted (happens every week)

we have >200 agents connected to this master and it grows, so a long term solution is to increase the CPU & Memory. But till we get bigger VMs, we have to baby sit every day to monitor the CPU load and memory to restart the mesos master service (which will force the re-election) as a precaution.

To avoid this manual effort, we are planning to force the re-election of this cluster on a specific interval.. say every 2days.

So my question here is, whether mesos master has support to force re-election like this, if so how, is it recommended and does it has any caveat?

Appreciate your time to answer and help me here!

Comment: Confused, the 3 nodes play the both roles as `mesos master` & `mesos slave`? Otherwise, how the master could out of memory, and what's the relationship with `The number of jobs`? If dedicated for master, the memory won't be high, if also act as slave, why not register less memory when agent register to master?

Comment: @lagom - sorry for the confusion, we run Mesos master in HA mode (3 node) and there are hundred of agents registered to this master and to be specific this is running on version 1.0.1

Comment: Yeah, this is strange, 200 agents are really a small number for mesos master control according to official claim. Back to your question, I never heard of force-election. As I know, mesos HA was controlled by zookeeper, only the zknode in zookeeper for corresponding mesos master disappear can the election starts. So I just suggest you to write a monitor script to monitor `CPU, MEM` for human, if exceed a threshold, kill current mesos master to let HA starts, put it in crontab of your 3 masters to make it as a routine task. Wait for other experts to give your better solution.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion @lagom . even I had similar line of thoughts to hack if I couldn't find any recommended configuration to force it!

Comment: @jay What version are you running?

Comment: @janisz - we are using 1.0.1

Comment: This could be a problem. If you can upgrade to the latest Mesos. There was enormous work done on performance. See blog posts [this](http://mesos.apache.org/blog/mesos-1-7-0-released/) and [that](http://mesos.apache.org/blog/mesos-1-7-0-performance-improvements/)

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation @janisz, but due to some tight dependency with the frameworks (Aurora & custom) which we use, it is not that easy to upgrade at this moment, but we are thriving to achieve it sooner. so looking for a solution/workaround with mesos 1.0.1 to run the business till we are ready to resize / upgrade our current infrastructure.

Comment: One thing that comes to my mind it `/state` endpoint. Check if you are not killing your master just by querying it.

Comment: sure, thanks @janisz!

Comment: Did you try killing one of the `mesos-masters` service using a CRON service ?